# Apt database out of sync

Tags: linux-mint, apt

[Linux Mint 19.3]

Not sure what happened, but I have a bunch of packages that have become conflicted with the apt database. After running `apt update`, (done with 3 different mirrors, including the default ones), I'm seeing some packages reporting this:

```
$ apt policy libpulse0
libpulse0:
  Installed: 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5
  Candidate: 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5
  Version table:
 *** 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4 500
        500 http://mirror.os6.org/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:11.1-1ubuntu7 500
        500 http://mirror.os6.org/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Here are my configured repos:

**official-package-repositories.list**

```
deb http://mirror.os6.org/linuxmint.com/packages tricia main upstream import backport 

deb http://mirror.os6.org/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror.os6.org/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror.os6.org/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner
```

As you can see, I somehow have a newer version of this package than the mirrors are reporting. I checked via **Update Manager**, and this package was updated on 12/11/2019 during my normal daily update routine. I didn't even notice this until I was trying to build the latest **QEMU**, and the command `apt-get build-dep qemu` started complaining about dependency conflicts.

Without going through every installed package, I have no idea how many packages this is affecting. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you have `bionic-proposed` enabled during your update on the 11th?

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I can remember, I was using the default Mint 19.2 Tina repos. I upgraded to Mint 19.3 on the 18th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5 of `pulseaudio` is [the version currently in `bionic-proposed`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5); this suggests that your system somehow picked updates from there, temporarily.

If that’s the case, there’s nothing to do, and nothing much to worry about: the packages will migrate from `-proposed` to `-updates`, and the repositories will catch up with your system (which is living a few days in the future, effectively).

Comment: Thanks for that. I checked my Timeshift snapshots from earlier in the month (1st to 11th, when the update occurred) and the `-proposed` repos were never activated. I'll just be patient.

Comment: Yes, there are a number of possible explanations for why you got proposed updates, and they don’t necessarily involve anything wrong on your system.

Comment: Interesting - thanks again.